# Find x instance of a variable in a string with php

Tags: php

I am trying to grab text from a string that begins after the 3rd instance of a repeating variable

```
t|1t|2t|3t|4
```

I want to return the number 3 by finding the 3rd "t|"

I know how to get the string:

```
$pc1 = 'start';
$pc2 = 'end';


$pcb = strpos($string, $pc1,+2);
$pce = strpos($string, $pc2);


$data_point = substr($string,$pcb,$pce - $pcb);
```

But if I search for "t|" inside $data_point, it always leaves me with the first one and not the third

Comment: I revised the question to clarify that I am parsing a text string not html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` the string into an array and get the number:

```
$arr = explode('t|', $string)
print_r($arr);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use explode, this give what is immediately after the end of the matched pattern.

```php
    function pattern_match($i = 0, $txt = "", $pattern = "")
    {
        $j = 0;
        
        while($j <= strlen($txt)) {
            if ($j >= strlen($pattern)) return true;
            
            if ($pattern[$j] != $txt[$i + $j]) return false;
            
            $j++;
        }
    }
    
    function scan($txt = "", $pattern = "")
    {
        $i = 0; $matches = [];
        while ($i <= strlen($txt)) {
            if(pattern_match($i, $txt, $pattern)) $matches[] = $i + strlen($pattern) - 1;
            
            $i++;
        }
        
        return $matches;
    }
    
    function get_nth($n = 0, $txt = "", $pattern = "", $j = 1) 
    {   
        $indicies = scan($txt, $pattern);
        
        return $indicies[$n] ? substr($txt, $indicies[$n] + 1, $j) : null;
    }
    
    $txt = "t|1t|2t|3t|xyz012";
    $pattern = "t|";
    
    var_dump(
        get_nth(0, $txt, $pattern),
        get_nth(1, $txt, $pattern),
        get_nth(2, $txt, $pattern),
        get_nth(3, $txt, $pattern, 3) // any char to the right
    )
    // string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(3) "xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the last occurance you need to use **strrpos**

```
  $original = '7853412365412390';
  $search = '123';
  $position = strrpos($original, $search);
```

$position will be 11. With substr you get 5.

For more informations: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php